# Do I need to use {each} syntax for a non-repeating section on a Cognito Forms custom template?

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm building a custom template for my Cognito Forms output, and I have some repeating and some non-repeating sections. Do I need the {each} syntax on the non-repeating sections? The Cognito Forms helpdesk says

"The each tag is used when referencing repeating sections and regular sections. For example, if your repeating section is named My Order, and you have a field in the section called Product, you can reference the Product field like so..."

However it only goes on to describe how to use on repeating sections, not on regular sections.